# Is it proper to use google map image in scientific paper?

Tags: copyright, graphics, elsevier

I have used a google map image as an illustration of street map within my study area. And I have submitted the paper containing this figure to a journal owned by Elsevier.

Meanwhile, the reviewer questioned about the copy right of the basemap which I have also concerned on.

Is it proper to use those maps from Google maps or Google Earth. I'm not familiar with the legal issues of the terms of use for Google Map/Earth.

Comment: Sure, this question is relevant to academia, but it really is about image rights in a specific contexts. Have you tried other sources?

Comment: The Google query "image rights Google maps"  took me here: https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/ Voting to close.

Comment: @Dirk you can change this to an answer though it is surprising that an academic as OP did the search him/herself

Comment: I would rather not, as I don't think that this question belongs here. Also: It seems like the real answer is "You have to ask Google following the instructions from the linked site."

Comment: Consider using Open Street Map: would be easier permissions-wise. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright